# Paypal delayed chain execute payment to specific receiver?

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm working on a Magento marketplace where the client would like to use paypal delayed chain as payment method. Here Client will hold the vendors payment for 15 days and then execute payments. The scenario is Client don't want to hold payments for highly credible vendors. He wants to pay them right away. But in delayed chain, we can't execute payments based on vendors.  When the time comes to pay vendors, all vendors will be paid at once based on transaction id or pay-key which used to create payment.

I need to implement this scenario in Magento. Does anyone have solution on this potential issue?

Comment: But how do I execute payments for one vendor from an order instead of all vendors in delayed chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deep about this issue, I found that paypal doesn't support what I asked from their API or the API is still isn't matured to accommodate the need. So we went with another solution to overcome this problem. Solution is not efficient but it's the only working solution as of now.

We have to go with checkout by vendor, so that we can execute payment based on vendor since each order is associated with a vendor.